# Help understanding 'God loves everyone equally, 100 percent.'

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I am trying to understand the article shown in the quote below:

> One is that God's love is like the sun -- he loves everyone equally and that means 100 percent. He loves bad people just as much as he loves good people. He loves Muslims, Catholics, homosexuals, politicians, millionaires, liars, dishonest people, murderers, school teachers, soldiers, Iraqis, Israelis, the mentally ill, Mother Teresa and Saddam Hussein equally, and his love is infinite. Just as the sun shines on everyone equally and the rain falls on everyone equally, so also **God loves everyone equally, 100 percent**.

How should I interpret the sentence "God loves everyone equally, 100 percent." (Marked as bold in the quote)? Does this mean "100 percent of God loves each and every one", or does this rather mean "God loves 100 percent of each and every person"?

Comment: The writer probably means that "everyone" applies to 100% of the people who have  ever lived, not to a lesser percentage, such as 50% or 95% of the people. This is the argument of the passage. The writer could also be alluding to 100% of God's love.  Anyway, it's not the clearest way to state what one means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that God loves every single person the exact same amount (that is, if love can even be quantified, and for this article, let's assume it can be). 100% of the love He gives to one person is the same amount of love He gives to anyone else. He won't love one person 100% and then love someone else 50% (which is to say, not as much).

Comment: Also, it means not only the same amount, but the maximum amount (100%). Combine that with 'his love is infinite' and the passage is saying God loves everyone an infinite amount.