# Created equal or created equally?

Tags: adverbs

The United States Declaration of Independence contains one of the most well known and enduring lines in English:

> We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created **equal**, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.

and was paraphrased by Michelle Obama in her speech at the Democratic National Convention:

> "All are created equal."

The Massachusetts Constitution contains

> All men are born free and **equal**...

and The Virginia Declaration of Rights contains

> ... all men are by nature **equally** free and independent ...

While I understand the Declaration of Independence to mean

> All **equally** have the same rights

Would it not have been more grammatically correct to use the adverb

> All are created **equally**

I realise that

> All are **equally** created

may have a different meaning.

Comment: No. In this case, "equal" is correct. The DoI isn't talking about *how* all men are created, but *that* all men are created equal. It is an equivalence: all men are equal by birth. In this use, "equal" is not an adverb.

Comment: Related: [What does the word “equally” mean in this context?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/93854/9161) I think visitors to that question might be interested in the answers here and vice-versa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Equal*, the adjective, is correct here.

*Created equally*, with the adverb, implies that some things are *more* and some are *less* "created"—which would presumably mean (it's not idiomatic English) that they owe their origins to a greater or lesser degree to some sort of act of creation, as opposed to having arising spontaneously.

*Equal* is not an adverb but a "subject-oriented predicate complement", a term which describes the subject and is attributed to it as a result of the action of the verb. Compare, for instance:

> Coffee was served black.
>   Coffee was served in large mugs.

*Black* and *in large mugs* are subject-oriented predicate complements.

*All men are created equal* thus means that all men (and women, too!) were created *as* equal—the creative act caused them to be equal.

Comment: Is it possible to see *in large mugs* as an obligatory adjunct? https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236760872_The_Pragmatics_of_Obligatory_Adjuncts

Comment: @KinzleB Neither *black* nor *in large mugs* is obligatory, and neither is an "adjunct".

Comment: That paper suggests the infelicitous use of "This house was built" and "a built house". An adjunct like "in 1990" or "recently" could be required. Perhaps it's different to OP's example.

Comment: @KinzleB A very interesting article. Note that Goldberg and Ackermann are discussing ***apparently*** obligatory constituents; they're asking under what pragmatic circumstances *some* constituent is required, and why, and they specifically point out pragmatic circumstances (eg, ex (25)) under which *no* further constituent is required

Comment: Did the serving cause the coffee to be black? Or did the serving merely act as a conduit for already-black coffee?  The crew of the Enterprise was beamed down intact.

Comment: @TRomano An apt question. Not exactly "cause", but there is certainly a degree of agency involved in the "black state" (and the mugs) in which the coffee was served.

Comment: I like my coffee ex nihilo, please.

Comment: @TRomano Alas, *Nothing will come of nothing*. Somebody's gotta exploit those pickers.

Comment: What about "his eyes opened wide"? What's the grammatical function of the adjectival phrase 'wide' here?

Comment: @KinzleB Again, it's a subject-oriented predicate complement.

Comment: It's a bit strange to say "eyes are/become wide", unlike "all men are equal".   CGEL calls the AdjP 'young' in 'he died young' a predicative adjunct rather than a predicative complement. Do you agree?

Comment: @KinzleB Mmm ... It's borderline. We say *Her eyes were wide* and have the compound *wide-eyed*. On the other hand, we also say *Her eyes were wide open*, and *open* as a verb is a causative, "cause to be open". I was reading something recently - McCawley? - involving semantic merger across syntactic categories; I'll see if I can find it.

Answer (score 5):

The attribute inheres in the created not in the act of creating.

You can take **are created** as a quasi-copula complemented by a predicate adjective that applies to that which is created.

We don't say **born freely** do we? **Created equal** is perfectly grammatical.

Answer (score 5):

"Created equal" means "created such that they are equal".

A homosexual man might say, *"Your God created me gay!"*.  This is the same grammar: *gay* is an adjective, complement to the verb *created*.

(And note, by the way, it cannot be: *"... created me gaily!"*)

"Created equally" is an awkward application of an adverb to a verb. A speaker who uses this might be making a mistake, having intended to say "created equal", or might be trying to say "created according to the same procedure, to the same level of completion".

"Equally" is usually a helping adverb in an adverbial phrase as in "equally well", "equally far" and so on.  By itself, it usually refers to something being done such that there are even proportions:

- "*The food rations were divided equally among the stranded passengers.*"
- "*Daniel treated his three children equally when it came to love or discipline.*"

To say, "created to the same level of completion, by the same procedure", we normally say "created *in the same way*".  *Equally* doesn't function very effectively as a synonym for *in the same way*; at least not in all the circumstances in which we can use *in the same way*.

Answer (score 1):

It reminds me of a slogan-like sentence: "make it possible". If we paraphrase that in a passive voice, we get this: "it is made possible". I think this follows the same structure or grammar as "all are created equal".